# Numpy replacing specific column index per row by using a list of indexes with nan

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying the following:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])

print a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

a[np.arange(len(a)), [1,0,2]] = 20 #--Code1

print a
array([[ 1, 20,  3],
       [20,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8, 20]])
```

However, if my index has `nan` in them as:

```
a[np.arange(len(a)), [1,np.nan,2]] = 20  #--Code2
```

It errors out.

What I was trying to do is, if there is `nan` present in the index, don't change anything.

i.e. I wanted to implement `Code2` above so that I can obtain the following:

```
    array([[ 1, 20,  3],
           [4,  5,  6],
           [ 7,  8, 20]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`masking`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) -

```
m = ~np.isnan(idx) # Mask of non-NaNs
row = np.arange(a.shape[0])[m]
col = idx[m].astype(int)
a[row, col] = 20
```

where, `idx` is the indexing array.

Sample run -

```
In [161]: a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])

In [162]: idx = np.array([1,np.nan,2])

In [163]: m = ~np.isnan(idx) # Mask of non-NaNs
     ...: row = np.arange(a.shape[0])[m]
     ...: col = idx[m].astype(int)
     ...: a[row, col] = 20
     ...: 

In [164]: a
Out[164]: 
array([[ 1, 20,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8, 20]])
```